# Python set anomaly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand how sets work when I try to get values from a list.
So when I run the code at the bottom

```
wordlist = ['hello',1,2,3]
wordSet = set(wordlist)
```

Output is

```
{3, 1, 2, 'hello'}
```

or something similar because set doesn't have a order.
But my point is, when I try to reach my list's first element, like using myList[0] when using it's value to create a set

```
wordlist = ['hello',1,2,3]
wordSet = set(wordlist[0])
```

I was expecting output to be

```
{'hello'}
```

but instead, I get

```
{'l', 'o', 'h', 'e'}
```

or one of randomized style.
My point is when I put my list in set function directly, it uses entire list to create a set, but when I want to create a set with using only first element in my list, it divides my string to characters.
Why does that happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `set` on an object will iterate the object. Strings are iterable, yielding individual characters. If you want a set containing only the first element of `wordlist`, you would need to use an iterable which only contains that element:

```
set([worldlist[0]])
```

Or, more directly, just use the curly braces:

```
{worldlist[0]}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Strings such as `'hello'` are iterable; `set()` converts iterables into sets.

To clarify,

```
set(('1', '1', '2', '3')) == {'1', '2', '3'}
set(['1', '1', '2', '3']) == {'1', '2', '3'}
set('1123') == {'1', '2', '3'}
```